# aws athena : how to make filter is required for column

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, information-schema

when I do a query on the table "information_schema .__ internal_partitions__" I get the following error message: GENERIC_INTERNAL_ERROR: filter is required for column: information_schema .__ internal_partitions __. table_schema

is it possible to add the same condition on a column in a table that I will create

tnx

Answer (score 0):

According to [PrestoDB GitHub](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/pull/9648/files), the backend Database behind Athena, this error only shows when you try to query the table_schema or table_name.

Answer (score 0):

As the error indicates you cannot query the whole table. You need to apply a filter on column table_schema as shown in below example:

```
SELECT *
FROM   information_schema.__internal_partitions__
WHERE  table_schema = 'default'
       AND table_name = 'cloudtrail_logs_test2'
ORDER  BY partition_number
```

Refer to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying-glue-catalog.html) doc for more examples around this.

Answer (score 0):

my question is: can I add a constraint to a column in another table that I am going to create.

for example if I have a table T1 with columns C1, C2 and C3.
I want to not allow any "select" unless there is a condition on C3.